# On google sheets, is there a reason this code isnt running?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onEdit(if getActiveRange()=A3:B500) {//Check to see if the cells edited are on this 
    rangemyFunction1(event);// trying to set off this function that has other functions nested
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? Where is rangemyFunction1? Why do you have an if in the parameter section of the function?

Comment: is this a copy/paste from your actual code?  The script editor will not even allow you to save a script with the syntax as presented, this isn't valid Javascript syntax. I can help you rewrite it, but want to be sure there isn't just a typo or copy/paste error in the question as presented.

Comment: Its copy of the actual code i just couldnt get it to work, i was trying to make it check for edit on this specific range A:B columns and then execute some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question

> Why my code is not working?

### Answer

> Wrong javascript syntax

Your code is not working because your JavaScript syntax is wrong because you can't write **if statement inside parameters**.

```js
function onEdit(if getActiveRange()=A3:B500) {//Check to see if the cells edited are on this 
    rangemyFunction1(event);// trying to set off this function that has other functions nested
```

Instead you have to write something like this:

```js
function onEdit() {
    if (getActiveRange() === "A3:B500") {
        rangemyFunction1(event);
        // do more stuff
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```

Check the [onEdit example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

More examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573969/save-a-sheet-as-pdf-with-onedit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695652/google-script-copy-row-to-other-sheet-onedit).